# Easy way to load an Array of NSDictionary into Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary

I need to import an external file as the initial data in my core data model.

I have an array of dictionaries, which includes dictionaries that contain key value pairs, including such things as key: firstName John, lastName Jones, etc.

I came up with the following to load the data, but I'm wondering if there is some more simple and elegant way of doing this that I'm not aware of.  I searched the the reference material on NSDictionary and NSArray, and I'm not finding something that seems to fit.

```
//my attempt to load an array of dictionaries into my core data file
-(void)loadUpNamesFromImportedFile
{
if (!self.context) {
    self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
}
ImportClientListFromFile *file = [[ImportClientListFromFile alloc]init];

self.clientListDictionary = [file fetchClientNamesFromFile];

self.clientNames = self.clientListDictionary;

// enumerate the dictionaries, in the array of dictionaries which are from an imported file
for (NSDictionary *attributeValue in self.clientNames) {
    ClientInfo *info = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClientInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    //create an array which identifies attribute names to be used as keys to pull information from the dictionary
    NSArray *keys = @[@"clientID",@"firstName",@"lastName",@"gender",@"phone",@"middleName",@"fullName"];

    //enumerate the keys array, and assign the value from the dictionary to each new object in the database
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [info setValue:[attributeValue valueForKey:key] forKeyPath:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not store your NsArray as a Transformable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dictionary only contains keys that are property names on your CLientInfo object you can remove the keys array you are creating and just use allKeys on the dictionary.

```
// enumerate the dictionaries, in the array of dictionaries which are from an imported file
for (NSDictionary *attributeValue in self.clientNames) {
    ClientInfo *info = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClientInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    //enumerate the keys array, and assign the value from the dictionary to each new object in the database
    for (NSString *key in [attributeValue allKeys]) {
        [info setValue:[attributeValue valueForKey:key] forKeyPath:key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cleaner:

```
-(void)loadUpNamesFromImportedFile {
    if (!self.context) {
        self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
    }
    ImportClientListFromFile *file = [[ImportClientListFromFile alloc] init];

    self.clientListDictionary = [file fetchClientNamesFromFile];

    self.clientNames = self.clientListDictionary;

    // enumerate the dictionaries, in the array of dictionaries which are from an imported file
    for (NSDictionary *attributeValue in self.clientNames) {
        ClientInfo *info = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClientInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
        [info setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:attributeValue];
    }
}
```